# ERROR: Insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query. EF + Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, edmx

When I update my model's `.edmx` in Visual Studio 2012 the following error occurs:

> Unable to generate the model because of the following exception: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.

Anyone know why? I only have two simple tables in the model?

Comment: Older SQL server does this. Upgrade the server (at least the SP version).

Answer (score 2):

Check resource governor and see if it is enabled.
This can happen in resource governor Is enable and resource pools was runnig.
Set resource governor disable.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I received this error when using EF with `SqlExpress 2014`. The reason was because I had throttled Sql's memory limitation in order to preserve RAM on my development machine - the fix was simply to [increase the memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx) again temporarily:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'max server memory', 1024;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

And then restart the `SqlServer` service.

Comment: +1 anecdotes. While we're on this, I've seen SQL Server do this because of lack of system memory in general. i.e. some other process is putting extreme memory pressure on the system.

Comment: we already have `max server memory = 2147483647`. (was updated by Ex-DBAs). But now we facing this while run query in SSMS. why?

Answer (score 0):

what sql version are you using for the edmx? SQL 2008? if yes, make sure you have SQL Server 2008 Service Pack 2 installed.

more info here

[FIX: "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982854)